# Dead Space 3 crashes upon load

Tags: pc, technical-issues, dead-space-3

Every time I try to load dead space 3 on my PC, the game will start, the screen goes black, etc. But after about 2-3 seconds of loading, the game instantly crashes. I have searched around for a solution for quite a while but can't seem to find anything, I've tried reinstalling multiple times without any luck. Are there any workarounds for this? Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your save file is corrupted, since reinstalling keeps the save files intact it does not change anything. I sorry but I think you will have to restart the game.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that has a joystick or any accessories: just unplug it.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? Can you expand on this? Did this help you?

Answer (score -2):

Have you made any updates regarding the graphics card driver or something similar? If not I think you should remove every data related to the game and reinstall it all over again.